# Deleting Auto complete email addresses gmail app

Tags: applications, gmail

I have a common contact with an old email address that keeps popping up on autocomplete when I send an email with my Gmail application. The contact for this person does not contain this email address and I have searched the desktop version of the contact as well and it's not there. How do I delete this old outdated email address from autocomplete on my Gmail application for my Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gmail autocompletes email addresses based both on previous communication and [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com).

You should edit the contact in question to remove the old email address from their contact entry on [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com), or in the Contacts app of your device, and if that doesn't work go into Settings - Apps and find Gmail and Clear Data on the app. Be aware that that this will erase all emails and data for Gmail that are stored locally on your device, it will not delete Gmail on the server, and it will be resynced to the device after you open the app again, but if you use Gmail for POP3 email access those emails may not be stored on the server and should be backed up first.

Comment: This does not worked for me, my unwanted contact (actually a mispell I once entered) is still there after all this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the above worked. When I typed a few characters into the TO field some very old email address would suggest itself, with 100% reliability.

Solution: touch and hold on that email address, and the device would ask you to confirm removing this "learned word".

Now I guess this could be a Samsung feature or a gmail app feature or an Android feature, but it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I am in this same boat (when I typed a few characters into the TO field an old email address which I used only ONCE because of a mispell would suggest itself, with 100% reliability). Sadly, touch-and-hold does nothing else than selecting that email address rather than pop-up that question. This is on a Samsung A50

Answer (score -1):

Please go to [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/u/0/preview/all) to manage this contact.